# Series: Finding the area of infinitely many triangles

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Compute the total area of the (infinitely many) triangles in the Figure.

The height of all triangles is $\dfrac67$. $x-$values for the bases of the triangles from left to right are as follows: $\dfrac{27}{64}$, $\dfrac9{16}$, $\dfrac34$, $1$, $\cdots$

[image]

Using the formula for the area of a triangle $\left(A = \dfrac12BH\right)$ as well as the fact that all the triangles have the same height of $\dfrac67$, I know that the area is equal to $\dfrac37B$. I'm not quite sure where to go from there when it comes to solving this, however.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: I would just like to say thank you to all those who have answered and all those willing to do so in the future. I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since the base $x$-values are increasing by a factor of $4/3$ in every new triangle, the ratio is greater $1$ and thus the bases are getting larger indefinitely. The area is not finite.

Comment: The geometric series is a diversion rather than a divergence :)

Answer (score 0):

From the picture, it looks as though the triangles are getting smaller and approaching the $y$-axis. IF SO, then you have a geometric series for their area which converges:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\frac{6}{7}\left(\frac{3^{n-1}}{4^{n-1}}-\frac{3^n}{4^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2}\frac{6}{7}\left(\frac{4}{3}-1\right)\frac{3^n}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{6}{7}\frac{1}{3}3=\frac{3}{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Note: OP has left an ambiguity in which direction the infinite triangles go, from left to right or from right to left. I've answered for both the cases**


I assume that the triangle's bases are decreasing indefenitely from right (at $x=1$) to $x=0$. Then, the area of the triangle decreases by a factor of $3/4$ from right to left. Assume the total area of triangles is $A$. If you exclude the largest triangle on the right, then the remaining area is just a scales down version of the original picture. Thus, it's area will be $\frac{3}{4}A$. Thus, we can say
$$\text{Area of Largest Triangle}+\frac{3}{4}A=A$$
$$3/28=1/4A$$
$$A=\frac{3}{7}$$

If the trangle's bases are increasing indefenitely towards the right, then the area is diverging and we cannot find it.

Comment: This is a good approach and is perfectly valid. (+1). Don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @hypergeometric Because it's wrong? The OP said it was increasing left to right! Only now did they edit their answer after I mentioned it.

Comment: @AndrewLi read the assumption I had made in the first line. I edited to show the actual case the OP meant in the last line after I realised I misinterpreted the question

Comment: It is not incorrect to say that the bases increase from left to right. The point OP should clarify is whether the number of triangles increase indefinitely to the right beyond $1$.

Comment: @hypergeometric Hmm yeah you're right. OP has talked only about the which direction the base increases, not in which direction it increases

Comment: @hypergeometric I posted a comment (now deleted) asking if they were increasing right to left as I initially assumed and they explicitly said no, it was left to right. They could be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLi I'll leave both the cases in my answer because of this ambiguity. Anyways the increases towards the right case is a pretty boring one, I'd prefer it to be increasing towards the left :P

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

The area of a triangle is half base times height, and since all triangles have equal height, the *total* area is half *total* base times height, i.e.
$$\frac 12\cdot 1\cdot \frac 67 = \color{red}{\frac 37}$$

The geometric series summation is a diversion :)

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious thing! +1

Comment: I don't understand this. If the base is getting larger, why would the area be finite?

Comment: The first triangle is the one on the right. Bases get smaller to the left.

Comment: @AndrewLi The triangles are arranged from right to left. The rightmost triangle is the largest, and the base keeps decreasing towards the left (Thats how i've interpreted it)

Comment: @PrathyushPoduval No. Did you read the question? I asked explicitly yesterday and they answered that they were increasing left to right.

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes I did. But the figure says otherwise (looking at the dots pointing towards the left)

Comment: @AndrewLi Uh oh, seems like OP mentioned in the comments it increases towards the right. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @PrathyushPoduval I was under the impression that line was just a half-way line since its the same format as the $6/7$ line. I asked the OP and you could ask again but I followed what the OP said.

Comment: If the triangles continue beyond $1$ on the right, then there would be a dotted line in the diagram to indicate that, but there isn't. The diagram is correct but perhaps the question is not tightly worded.

Comment: @hypergeometric Is that a convention? If so, I'll delete my answer but I'd want confirmation from the OP

Comment: The point OP should clarify is whether the number of triangles increase indefinitely to the right beyond 1.  Anyway if a question asks for the total area of triangles which get infinitely bigger the answer is obviously infinity, which doesn't make it much of a question in the first place. So my solution assumes that the diagram is correct but the question is less than accurately worded.